# Enable Infinite/Endless Scrolling in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

Is there a way to enable endless scrolling (i.e. no pagination) for my Tumblelog? I have browsed through the [settings](https://www.tumblr.com/preferences) and selected "Enable endless scrolling" though this seems to only work for the Dashboard.

Is there a setting to achieve the same for a personal blog such that I can turn it on and off or must one manually code it into their Tumblr theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best explanation I know of is [here](http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling), but note that not all layouts allow for infinite scrolling. The popular [Papercuts](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/2807), for example, does not.